# select randomly from dropdown list?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My html sample code is,

```
 <div class="list">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul role="menu">
            <li class="rsbListItem">one</li>
            <li class="rsbListItem">two</li>
            <li class="rsbListItem">three</li>
            <li class="rsbListItem">four</li>
            <li class="rsbListItem">five</li>
            <li class="rsbListItem">six</li>
            <li class="rsbListItem">seven</li>
            <li class="rsbListItem">eight</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i write Selenium scripts for this, and each time when i run it should select randomly.

I have tried to pick random elements,but it's selecting the same element each time. Here is my code.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='menu']"));
Random rand = new Random();
int list= rand.nextInt(options.size());
options.get(list).click();
```

Comment: have you tried something ? Start by accessing a specific value (with a constant index), then change that constant to get a Random value. There you have the way to find a solution. If you have a problem with one of those two steps, start by diong some research. But please don't simply ask for a solution without even trying.

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't work, that's why am asking help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is not my thing but

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='menu']"));
```

This will return a list of `WebElement` match your request. So you should get the element (should be only one I guess) to work with it. You could also use `findElement` I guess.

Then, you will need to get every `Option` in the select you have.

```
List<WebElement> selects = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='menu']"));
Random rand = new Random();
for(WebElement select : selects){
    List<WebElement> options = // get every option in it
    int list = rand.nextInt(options.size());
    options.get(list).click();
}
```

Comment: When i use 'getOptions()' to get all the options from the dropdown , i need to use 'Select' . But 'Select' is used only in 'select' tagname, for other tagname like 'div' or 'ul' it shows me an error like **org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"**

Comment: @User I can't really help more, I don't use `Selenium` myself. But in HTML, a dropdown is create like `<select><option></option></select>`. Not with `<ul><li></li></ul>` This might be your first mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Locate the dropdown menu
WebElement drpdown = driver.findElements(By.id("id of the dropdown menu"));

// click the dropdown menu
drpdown.click();

//Get the list of dropdown options
List<WebElement> itemsInDropdown = driver.findElements(By.id("id of the dropdown list"));

// Get the size of dropdown list
int size = itemsInDropdown.size();

// Generate the random number
int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, size);

// Clicking on random value
itemsInDropdown.get(randomNumber).click();
```

Comment: Adding explanation to your answer would help

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.